# Get 'undefined' when calling AzureDevOps API multiple times

Tags: javascript, api, azure-devops

I am calling the AzureDevOps-API see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

I have an array with workitem ids. The size of the array is 501. You can just call the API with 200 workitem ids in one time so I have the following code:

```
  async *getWorkItemsFromTimelogData():AsyncGenerator<any>{
    let uniqueIds = [...new Set(WORKITEM_IDS)];

     for (const c of chunk(uniqueIds, MAX_BATCH_SIZE)) {
        const res = await this.get<any>(`wit/workitems?ids=${c}&$expand=all`);
        for (const item of res?.data?.value ?? []) {
          yield item;
        }
      }
  }
```

The first call with the first 200 Workitem Ids works fine. In the second and third count in the loop I get 'undefined' for 'res'. I have no idea how can that happen because in an other program the exact same approach with the same loop works fine. In the second and third call there are ids in 'c'. 200 in the second call and 101 in the third call. How can that happen?

This is the code in the other program which works finde:

```
for (const c of chunk(ids, MAX_BATCH_SIZE)) {
  const res = await this.get<WorkItemResponse>(
    `wit/workitems?ids=${c}&$expand=all`
  );
  for (const item of res?.data?.value ?? []) {
    yield item;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are some of the other programs in which you claim it works? Show us some examples.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have edited the code from the other program.